# How do you make a bot send a message to every server it is in discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

Can anyone help me? I don't know how to do this, but I want to make my bot send a message to every server it is in and if it doesn't have perms to do it, it can just ignore it. How do you do it?

Comment: Do you have any code that we can see? StackOverflow isn't a tutorial service where coders write code for other people. Please restructure your question with code so we can better assist you.

Comment: It's a great question. I'm here because I have the same question. It's easy to write a bot that only accesses one server but making a bot public means that it will need to be multi server aware. It's almost completely undocumented anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Using v11.2 of discord.js

const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client();

// So you can see when it's ready
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('On Discord!');
});

client.on('message', () => {
    if (message.content === "!sendguildmessages") {
        var guildList = client.guilds.array();
        try {
            guildList.forEach(guild => guild.defaultChannel.send("messageToSend"));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Could not send message to " + guild.name);
        }
    }
});
```

The Bot will send messages when you type !sendguildmessages into a channel the bot can read messages from.